# Large json data is not decoding in php

Tags: php

I have a large JSON data which I'm getting from a `base64_decode` and is not decoding in PHP.

`$cartData = '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'`

And PHP code is 
`$decodedCart_data = base64_decode($cartData);
$cartDecodeData = json_decode($decodedCart_data, true);
print_r($cartDecodeData);`

Returned JSON is

```
{"token":"284ce6f6d229702859fce86bb2fe41f0","note":null,"attributes":{},"original_total_price":135000,"total_price":135000,"total_discount":0,"total_weight":25000,"item_count":1,"items":[{"id":30117650006101,"properties":{},"quantity":1,"variant_id":30117650006101,"key":"30117650006101:8eb79315625facc5ab56262d18eeba1c","title":"Steel stationery cupboard with 2 shelves. 5 Colour options. - Hammer Tone Grey","price":135000,"original_price":135000,"discounted_price":135000,"line_price":135000,"original_line_price":135000,"total_discount":0,"discounts":[],"sku":"FAB0303-2","grams":25000,"vendor":"Fabulous Products","taxable":true,"product_id":4096561086549,"product_has_only_default_variant":false,"gift_card":false,"final_price":135000,"final_line_price":135000,"url":"/products/steel-cupboards-south-africa?variant=30117650006101","featured_image":{"aspect_ratio":1,"alt":"steel cupboards South Africa","height":600,"url":"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0103/5249/2629/products/Steel_Cupboard_2_shelves_Hammer_Tone_Grey.jpg?v=1569275380","width":600},"image":"https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0103/5249/2629/products/Steel_Cupboard_2_shelves_Hammer_Tone_Grey.jpg?v=1569275380","handle":"steel-cupboards-south-africa","requires_shipping":true,"product_type":"Steel Cupboards","product_title":"Steel stationery cupboard with 2 shelves. 5 Colour options.","product_description":"Steel Stationery Cupboard with 2 shelves.\nProduct made to order so delivery is 7 to 14 days from order placement.\n\nSteel cupboards carry a 10 year factory warranty. One year replacement guarantee\nCupboard includes two shelves and lockable handle supplied with 2 keys.\nStandard�powder coated�colours are Ivory Karoo and Hammertone Grey. Black, white and hammer tone grey with blue doors will require 21 days for manufacturing.\nDelivery arranged to anywhere in Gauteng South Africa only.\n\n\n\n900mm(H) x 900mm(W) x 450mm(D) with 2 adjustable shelves. Weight: 25kg.\n\n\n\n\n","variant_title":"Hammer Tone Grey","variant_options":["Hammer Tone Grey"],"options_with_values":[{"name":"Colours","value":"Hammer Tone Grey"}],"line_level_discount_allocations":[],"line_level_total_discount":0}],"requires_shipping":true,"currency":"ZAR","items_subtotal_price":135000,"cart_level_discount_applications":[]}
```

Comment: _which is not decoding in PHP...._ What happens there? What errors/issues are you facing?

Comment: Returns nothing when I'm giving the above json.

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://3v4l.org/IVr1S

Comment: Works for me...returns an array as expected

Comment: Could be a copy/paste issue so that what we're seeing is not what you're getting. You can check for [json_last_error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)/[json_last_error_msg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) to see why it's not decoding.

Comment: But it is still not showing any data.

Comment: var_dump `$data`. What does it contain?

Comment: String 2291 showing with var_dump

Comment: @manaspaul is the code here the exact code in you application?

Comment: You should look at @aynber's comment about json_last_error_msg(). That should tell you what the issue it ran into.

Comment: Actually I'm getting this data from a base64decode. See the full code here.```$encodedCart_data = $_REQUEST['cart_data'];
$decodedCart_data = base64_decode($encodedCart_data);
$cartDecodeData = json_decode($vp, true);
print_r($cartDecodeData);```

Comment: _$cartDecodeData = json_decode($vp, true);....._??? Really? Did you mean `$decodedCart_data` insetad of `$vp`? Boy, oh boy!

Comment: No actually ```json_decode($decodedCart_data,true)```. I have pasted it wrong above.

Comment: ok.. I'm out here

Comment: With json_last_error_msg and your code, I'm getting `'Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded'`

Comment: I have encoded the data with JQuery  ` var parseJsonData = JSON.stringify(product);
                //console.log(parseJsonData);
                var cart_data = window.btoa(parseJsonData); ` . It is working until now

Comment: It's the `Standard�powder coated�colours`, which is probably smart quotes?

Comment: Please advise how to remove this type of quotes from my JSON data.

Comment: I was able to get it to decode with `json_decode(utf8_decode($cartDecodeData));` which gave `Standard?powder coated?colours` for that string. I've been trying to remember if there's another way to get the quotes to change instead.

Comment: Your solution worked for me @aynber. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (possible) smart quotes around `powder coated` is messing up the json string. To fix it, use

```
json_decode(utf8_decode($cartDecodeData));
```

which will convert those quotes.